# gnuplot option arg -persist does not work under win7 console

Tags: gnuplot

In Win7 console, the option -persist seems not work? 
For example,

`gnuplot -persist -c "myscript.plt" "mydata.csv" "myoutput.png"`,

this command works all right and I get the file "myoutput.png" as I expect, but the gnuplot screen does not appear(NO `exit` command used in myscript.plt). Why? And how to make the gnuplot screen showes in my example?

At the beginning of "myscript.plt":

```
set datafile separator comma
set term pngcairo enhanced size 2018,1536 transparent
datafile=ARG1
set output ARG2
```

Comment: just a thought... why would you expect a gnuplot screen to appear if you are creating a png-output? Your script is creating a png output and that's it. No need for a gnuplot screen to persist. Change your terminal e.g. to wxt and the gnuplot screen should appear and stay.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get this `-c` Option from? I couldn't find it in the gnuplot help.
I tried one of my scripts with `-c` and observe a flashing of the gnuplot screen.

*Edit:*

actually, in the first version I tried a script which didn't have arguments and generating a `wxt` output.
If I use terminal `pngcairo` as output I also get the `png` output but no flashing and no persitent gnuplot screen. Actually, why would you expect a gnuplot screen to show up if you are not using an interactive terminal like `wxt` or `qt`? You are just creating a `png` file and that's it.

Comment: `-c` is the "command" option.  `gnuplot -c A B C` is executed as "call A with ARG1=B and ARG2=C".  The command as shown looks correct to me.

Comment: thank you @Ethan for your explanation. Now, I called a script A which had the arguments B and C, like the OP's one. Output file created. No problem with Win7.

Comment: Many thanks all. A gnuplot screen will show the plot result immediately. A png file will store the result but need another step to show the png result. I need both which is the reason to post this question.

Comment: what you can do in your code is: create your PNG output, then switch the terminal, e.g. to wxt or qt and do `replot`. However, this will not work with `multiplot`.